# Get $_SERVER variables in zf2 within controller

Tags: php, controller, zend-framework2, server, superglobals

Within a controller, how do I get `$_SERVER` variables in zf2?

For example, I would like to get `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, and so on.

I have tried using the following:

```
$this->getRequest()->getServer();
```

but this results in:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Http\Request::getServer()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get $_SERVER values from within a controller, I was able to do:

```
$request    = new \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request();
$httpHost   = $request->getServer('HTTP_HOST');
$remoteAddr = $request->getServer('REMOTE_ADDR');
```

Since I am answering my own question, I would be curious to see if there are any other recommended solutions.

Answer (score 2):

if your controllers extends AbstractActionController, you can use `$this->getRequest()->getServer()->get('REMOTE_ADDR');` in zf2 v2.4

```
class ListController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $addr = $this->getRequest()->getServer()->get('REMOTE_ADDR');

        \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($addr); die();
    }
}
```